# python- TypeError: func must be callable

Tags: python, apscheduler

I want to use `apscheduler.scheduler` in my project and this is my code

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

TOKEN = "****"

sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

def my_job(text):
    print(text)

def main() :
    job = sched.add_date_job(my_job('25'), '2017-09-08 14:08:05', args=['text'])
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write('.'); sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I got this exception

```
25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\+faeze\workspace\testHelloWorld\src\test\testDateTime.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\+faeze\workspace\testHelloWorld\src\test\testDateTime.py", line 16, in main
    job = sched.add_date_job(my_job('25'), '2017-09-08 14:08:05', args=['text'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\scheduler.py", line 318, in add_date_job
    return self.add_job(trigger, func, args, kwargs, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\scheduler.py", line 284, in add_job
    options.pop('coalesce', self.coalesce), **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\job.py", line 47, in __init__
    raise TypeError('func must be callable')
TypeError: func must be callable
```

where is my mistake??

**update:** what does `TypeError: func must be callable` mean?

Comment: It means the wrong variable is being passed to the add_job method, and the add_job method is receiving a variable/non-callable instead of an actual function

Comment: 'func' is the parameter for your methods, it tries to call func() at some point and it cant.. for example func = '10'... func() will do nothing.. number 10 is not callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify the following line.

```
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, '2017-09-08 14:08:05', ('25',))
```

This means my_job method will be called at the specified time with argument 25

Comment: This is also wrong. The "args" argument is supposed to be a list or a tuple. With this, you would get an error "args must be a non-string iterable".